Why is Trump not prosecuted before a military court?
It's been well over 3 years now since January 6. Trump has been indicted for election interference. My question is simple. Since he was the Commander in Chief, why has he never been in a military trial? Why has he not been charged with treason? Surely there must be a law that prohibits a sitting commander in chief from meddling in the election.

The presidency is a civilian office, but even if the President were a military officer, he couldn't be court-martialed while in office since he has no superior officer; and after he leaves office, he is no longer commander in chief, so the premise fails.

Generally speaking, holding court martials for civilians is a sure sign of a tinpot autocracy.

"Surely there must be a law that prohibits a sitting commander in chief from meddling in the election": I would be a bit surprised if such a provision existed in the uniform code of military justice.  It's available online; have you looked?

He’s not a member of the military
Being commander-in-chief does not make one a soldier. Therefore, he’s not subject to military law.
